# salesforce1 lightning component not refreshing after content changed

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have a component which has been exposed to salesforce1 via a custom tab.
After making a change to this component and saving the updates are not reflecting in the salesforce1 mobile application. i.e. adding the word "updated" in the code below.

If we include the component within a lightning application then the application does render the latest change when previewing from the developer console.

The following is our simple test component which we have been modifying the text message.

refreshTest.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >

<!-- required -->
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS100/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />

<div class="slds">
    <div > 
      <div class="slds-notify_container">
        <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error slds-theme--alert-texture" role="alert">
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Info</span>
          <h2>Some content updated</h2> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to why these changes are not reflecting in iOS or Android salesforce1 apps?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. See https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008dkwAAA. There are several workarounds you can use now. We're actively working to fix the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Kevin V.  Just tried this out in new release and issue is still somewhat present.  Bad -  mobile devices do not see intimidate refresh of changed content.  Good - hard closing the salesforce1 app and relaunching it refreshes the content.  The prior solution was to log out and log back in which wasn't manageable for our users.  In a perfect world it would be nice if we could make updates without having to hard close the salesforce1 application and restart ( or tell this to the application users).